# How to log out as root user in command prompt after creating non-root user

Tags: terminal, kali-linux

I'm trying to follow this tutorial: [How to add remove user (standard user/non-root) in Kali Linux?](http://www.blackmoreops.com/2013/11/27/how-to-add-remove-user-standard-user-non-root-in-kali-linux/)

The last step on page 1 says to logout and then back in as `user1` but it doesn't specify how to do that...is there a way, or does he mean to logout of root via desktop and then back in as `user1`, followed by opening another terminal window...the pictures he shows always show `root@kali:~` so that is why I thought they didn't mean to logout via desktop..

Forgot to mention...the only way I can think to do this was to use `su user1`...but that changes the address at the top of the terminal window to `user1@kali:/root`....I'm guessing this isn't what the tutorial was advising to do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To logout from UNIX or Linux you can either:

1. type `exit` and press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>
2. on a command line where you haven't typed anything press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd>

to log out.

Comment: my pleasure :)  I agree `su` is not what they had in mind, but it will come in handy later.  Check out `sudo` too for switching users.